# how to create weighted 2D array from networkx object in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I'm completely new to Python (and programming in general). A program I'm using has generated a gpickle file, the contents of which I would like to visualize in a 2D array.

This is what I've done so far:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

P = np.load('/pathtoobject.gpickle')
```

This results in this line of text:

```
networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x1d217d0
```

I've been able to create an undirected graph using...

```
nx.draw(P)
plt.show()
```

...but I would like to create a weighted 2D array, if possible. I do know that the object has 83x83 points.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you expect as output?

Comment: something like this, if possible: https://scipy-lectures.github.io/plot_directive/pyplots/numpy_intro_2.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a graph such as `G`:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2014)
A = np.random.randn(83, 83)
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)
```

you could use `nx.to_numpy_matrix` to obtain the graph's adjacency matrix. As ASGM suggested, you could then plot the "heatmap" using `plt.matshow`:

```
B = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)
plt.matshow(B)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

Comment: this worked perfectly! I've never used python before, and you really made it clear for me~ thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might try converting the networkx graph into a "dictionary of dictionaries" using [networkx.convert.to_dict_of_dicts](http://networkx.lanl.gov/archive/networkx-1.1/reference/generated/networkx.convert.to_dict_of_dicts.html), or a [SciPy adjacency matrix](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html).  Then you could use something like matplotlib's [`matshow()`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/matshow.html) to visualize it.

Comment: Glad to help (though @unutbu's answer is even more helpful!)